# \newfontfamily undefined control sequence

Tags: tables, fonts, errors

I am producing a latex document in rmarkdown. I want to change the typeface used in the tables.
I am following this answer on stack overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720299/rmarkdown-different-font-types-in-table-using-kable

However, I can't even get the first part to work.  I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \newfontfamily
```

This is my YAML:

```
---
title: "Queries"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \newfontfamily\helvetica[Path= Fonts/, ItalicFont = {Helvetica italic}, BoldFont = {Helvetica bold}]{Helvetica}
- \newenvironment{ctable}{\helvetica }{}
- \newenvironment{capctable}[1][t]{\begin{table}[#1]\centering\helvetica}{\end{table}}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
---
```

What am I doing wrong to \newfontfamily? I have also tried removing `, ItalicFont = {Helvetica italic}, BoldFont = {Helvetica bold}` but have the same error

If I rearrange the order of my `header-includes` parameters as follows

```
---
title: "Queries"
header-includes:
- \newfontfamily\helvetica[Path= Fonts/ ]{Helvetica}
- \newenvironment{ctable}{\helvetica }{}
- \newenvironment{capctable}[1][t]{\begin{table}[#1]\centering\helvetica}{\end{table}}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
---
```

I get a similar but different error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \newfontfamily
                   \helvetica[Path= Fonts/ ]{Helvetica}
```

Comment: You need to load the `fontspec` package in order to use the `\newfontfamily` macro.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I just forgot to add `latex_engine: xelatex`